# How to make RPI run script without WIFI

Tags: python, bluetooth, wireless

I have a RPI with a python script on it that makes the camera record every time you hit enter, and I would like to connect to the pi from my phone or laptop via Bluetooth or another way so I can run this script. dose anyone know how I could pull this off?

Comment: Maybe something like Bluedot could help you. https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2017/04/bluedot-bluetooth-remote-for-raspberry.html

Comment: thanks @ukBaz this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem using blue dot

https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2017/04/bluedot-bluetooth-remote-for-raspberry.html

Answer (score 0):

Please open the .bashrc service and add the application of the path you want to run and reboot the R-pi and your application will run even without the WiFi.